# Code-Runner: /bin/sh: cscript: command not found

Tags: c#, vscode-code-runner

I'm on Linux and currently trying to run a simple Hello World-program in C# using visual studio code.
The VSC for Linux, Arch Linux to be precise, is 'code'. I installed the extension 'Code Runner', but everytime I click on the 'Play/Execute'-Button in the upper right corner, it says:

```
[Running] cscript "/path/to/my/file/learning.cs"
/bin/sh: cscript: command not found
```

I can compile it with `csc learning.cs` and executing it with `mono learning.exe` just fine, but the built in code-runner VSC extension does not seem to work. I thought about adding 'cscript' to PATH but I don't know where it is located at.
I read on here that this problem exists for quite some time now, maybe someone found a solution? Or I am just really blind or dumb for not seeing an obvious fix.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing this is because you won't have access to `cscript.exe` through a Linux Shell. Is code-runner designed to run in Linux? But also you wouldn't call `cscript` to execute [tag:c#] it's for Active Scripting languages like [tag:vbscript] and [tag:jscript].

Answer (score 0):

Fix:
in vscode, go to preferences, then settings. Type `Code-runner: Executor Map`
Click `Edit in settings.json`

```
Under "code-runner.executorMap":
```

replace

```
csharp: cscript
```

with

```
csharp: dotnet run
```